# Intel xdk - Convert Windows zip to exe

Tags: intel

On Intel XDK , after "create Windows package" , I want to convert the zip file  to exe file via Phonegap or some other program.  Is it possible to do that inside Intel Xdk, with config.txt or name.xdk or name.xdke?
Thanks

Comment: You can use Phonegap to convert it to appx. But you need to  have cordova 6.5.0 on Intel xdk. If you don't know how to do this I will tell you, it easy

Comment: Yes, any suggestion will be great..